# Connect to FTP via Shell Script issue

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ftp

While I am able to log in fine manually through the command line, for some reason my log in fails when I try to programmatically log in my Unix Shell script. I am using the same exact script which is successful for another FTP server and I know the values I’m passing are correct. Could this be a configuration issue on the FTP server side?

I get the error: 530 User cannot log in. Login failed.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
ftp -inv $FTPSERVER << EOF
user $USERNM $PASS
lcd $DLPATH
binary
prompt
mget *.txt
bye
EOF
```

Comment: I would expect this to work, given that you can connect manually. Are there any special characters in $PASS? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter yes there is one special character. An exclamation point.

Comment: @shellter there is also a Back Slash in the user name due to having to add the domain. Would that cause an issue?

Comment: OK, I figured out the issue. I removed the domain and Back Slash from $USERNM and it worked!

Comment: Sorry, was away for a little while. Glad  you worked it out.